# How to set field for ::create in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I use this method to create new row in DB:

```
$input = $request->all();
return Recipient::create([$input]);
```

How I can add additional field to `$input` with an value?

I tried:

```
$input["user_id"] = Auth::id();
```

But when I display query INSERT, I can not see field `user_id`

Comment: You want to add column to the table?

Comment: No I want to add new input field in `$input = $request->all();` This fiels is not trasnfered in request, but exists in table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you probably don't set `$fillable` property in `Recipient` model. You should add `user_id` there:

```
 $fillable = [ ..., 'user_id'];
```

However merging input is usually not the best way to deal with such things. If you have set relationships properly, it should be possible to do something like this:

```
Auth::user()->recipients()->create($request->all());
```

Answer (score 1):

## Update

Like @Marcin Nabialek said: add 'user_id' to the `$fillable` array. And, his solution is cleaner.

## Merge

The method `merge` is what you're looking for: `Merge new input into the current request's input array.`

```
$request->merge(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id]);
Recipient::create($request->all());
```

See the api documentation here: https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_merge

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what exactly you are looking for. Suppose you have 2-3 fields `user_id`, `title`, `content`. For inserting into the database you need to do following:

```
$input = new Recipient(['title'=>'You title', 'content'=>'Your content']);
$input->save();
```

It will save two fields with the incremented user_id.

Answer (score 0):

Bro, You're using wrong method,
Try this one:

```
  $input["user_id"] =Auth::user()->id;
```